# How do I properly add a background-color?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I found a free custom Radiobutton which I implemented within my own code. But I'm struggling to make it work and having some issues with the functionality. Whenever I add a background-color to the parent object it doesn't change the buttons color when pressed. I have tried changing Z-index values on the parent object and some other things but nothing seems to work.

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
  transition: all 300ms linear; 
}

[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked){
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.checkbox-tools:checked + label,
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
  transition: all 300ms linear; 
}
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label{
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.checkbox-tools:checked + label{
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.checkbox-tools:checked + label::before,
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(298deg, yellow, green);
  z-index: -1;
}

/* .bg-color {
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: -999;
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    /> 
    
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container bg-color">
      <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col-12">
          <input class="checkbox-tools test-tools" type="radio" name="typ-av-el" id="elhandel-button">          
          <label class="for-checkbox-tools" for="elhandel-button">
            <p>button 1</p>
          </label>
          <!--  -->
          <input class="checkbox-tools test-tools" type="radio" name="typ-av-el" id="elnät-button">
          <label class="for-checkbox-tools" for="elnät-button">
            <p>button 2</p>
          </label>
        <div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

The code snippet I sent works, but when the bg-color class is enabled it stops working. You no longer see the buttons changing into the linear-gradient color. Any solutions for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include code that doesn't work?

Comment: You can see that I unchecked a CSS class called bg-color, which if enabled makes the buttons stop working.

Comment: why don't use `.checkbox-tools{}` instead of `.bg-color {}` ?

Comment: On my webpage I want the background-color to cover the whole container, not only the radiobutton.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looked for? I think the background-image was attached to the wrong CSS scenario, as it should be visible when you clicked it right?

- I edited it with a fix for the Transition. I cant acces the change where it occurs with a normal Transition so i used a real keyframes-animation to get the same effect

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
  transition: all 300ms linear; 
}

[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked){
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}


.checkbox-tools:checked + label,
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
   
}
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label{
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.checkbox-tools:checked + label{
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
   animation: example 300ms forwards;
}
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.checkbox-tools:checked + label::before,
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.bg-color {
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: -999;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {background-color: white;}
  to {background-image: linear-gradient(298deg, yellow, green);}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    /> 
    
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container bg-color">
      <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col-12">
          <input class="checkbox-tools test-tools" type="radio" name="typ-av-el" id="elhandel-button">          
          <label class="for-checkbox-tools" for="elhandel-button">
            <p>button 1</p>
          </label>
          <!--  -->
          <input class="checkbox-tools test-tools" type="radio" name="typ-av-el" id="elnät-button">
          <label class="for-checkbox-tools" for="elnät-button">
            <p>button 2</p>
          </label>
        <div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! Any way to also get the same animation? There is a slightly different animation between the two.

Comment: which animation do you mean exactly? then i can look into it

Comment: "transition: all 300ms linear" is the one. When I try both buttons there is a slight difference. The first buttons transitions a bit slower, while yours changes color straight away.

Comment: i edited it with a keyframes animation. You can style whatever you need there and set a delay and duration. Transition doesnt work in the scope the image is now, its a bit hard to explain

Comment: Wow, this is tricky. I can't seem to replicate the same result, even though it's really close.

Comment: yeah it's a bit tricky cause you have a lot of different layers of style for different scenarios. best way is to just play around with CSS a bit. developer Console in the Browser helps a lot too